# PLC programming

Tags: programmable-logic

In the figure below it says if the contact used is NC, then program it in the PLC as NO. Why?

Also, the diagram on the left for example the stop pushbutton which is connected to IN 1, is a NC switch and it's programmed in the PLC top rung also as a NC which contradicts the above instruction.

So, what is meant to program the contacts opposite to their wiring?

Source:

Electrical Motor Controls for Integrated Systems Applications Manual, Fourth Edition

ISBN 978-0-8269-1220-6

2009 by American Technical Publishers, Inc.

Author  Glen A. Mazur

[image]

Comment: Where's the highlight?

Comment: What PLC is it - please link to the device.

Comment: @Transistor, The 'highlight' refers to the 'Programming Notes' at the top right corner!

Comment: @Andy aka , I added the book details Sorry I really forgot to add it the first time. Is it enough or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the figure below it says if the contact used is NC, then program it in the PLC as NO. Why?

The idea here is that STOP buttons should be built and wired so that they fail in a safe manner. For this reason they should be wired using a normally closed (NC) contact.

[image]

*Figure 1. An industrial contact block. (This one is shown beside a rotary switch. The block can be attached to a push-button head.) Modified from image on [Electrical Academy](https://electricalacademia.com/motor-control/push-button-switch-types-and-circuit-diagram/).*

- The contacts should be forced apart by action of the button. A failure of the spring should keep the contacts open.
- Multiple stop buttons around a machine should be wired in series so that pressing any one breaks the loop and causes the machine to stop.
- Loss of power on the stop line causes a stop.
- Wire break or loose terminal causes a stop.

The START button, on the other hand, will use a normally open tending to fail in a safe manner but note that it relies on a spring to open the contacts when the button is released so it is not truly fail-safe.

> Also, the diagram on the left for example the stop pushbutton which is connected to IN 1, is a NC switch and it's programmed in the PLC top rung also as a NC which contradicts the above instruction.

[image]

*Figure 2. The program listing is incorrect. This logic would require the NC stop button to be held pressed to allow FORWARD or REVERSE to be selected.*

The program listing should use an `-| |-` contact.

**General comment on NO / NC terminology**

The NO and NC terminology has been carried over from relay and switch terminology but it's a bad fit for PLC logic as there is no "normal" for it. e.g., The stop button input is usually high as would a motor's thermal overload. The start button is usually low as would many sensors' output but not all.

Allen-Bradley tried to address this with their `XIC -] [-` (eXamine If Closed) and `XIO -]/[-`  (eXamine If Open) syntax but it's not quite clear.

Would `True when High` and `True when Low` be better? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

In hard-wired logic, a 'fail-safe' circuit mandates that an 'NO' contact of the 'start' push-button switch and 'NC' contact of the 'stop' push-button switch be used. A 'start' push-button switch wire-break would then disable a 'start' while the same with a 'stop' push-button switch would enable a stop.

In the case of a PLC too, the 'NO' contact of the 'start' button and 'NC' contact of the 'stop' button are to be wired to its inputs. The 'start' input would then need to be programmed as 'NO' and so would the 'stop' input, for the logic to work.

The same applies to the overload relay and the limit switches.

That diagram, at the top left corner, is erroneous.